# Scala: Consecutive id in set

Tags: scala, functional-programming, set

I have a class `Edge` (like in a graph) with the following signature.

```
class Edge(b1: Block, b2: Block, var id: Int, arity: Int)
```

`Block` is a class - what it does, is not interesting.

Now, there is already a set `s` with some objects that provide the source and targets. I would now like to give those edges a consecutive id (starting by 1, next block shall get 2, and so on....).

I currently did this by first giving all a 1 as id and later on I run a function `createLabels` that re-assigns the labels (see below).

```
val edges = s map { x => new Edge(x.getSrcBlock, x.getDstBlock, 1, getArity(x))}

def createLabels: Unit = {
  var i: Int = 0
  for(e <- edges) {
    e.id = i
    i = i+1
  }
}
```

However, I don't like this solution because I want to avoid those variables and it is procedural style rather than functional style. Can you give me a hint how I could do this better?

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`zipWithIndex`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Set@zipWithIndex:scala.collection.immutable.Set[%28A,Int%29]):

```
case class Edge(b1: Block, b2: Block, id: Int, arity: Int)

val edges = s.zipWithIndex.map { case (x, index) => 
  Edge(x.getSrcBlock, x.getDstBlock, index, getArity(x))
}
```

Comment: One minor caution: the OP posts in his/her question: `starting by 1, next block shall get 2, and so on....).` Note that `zipWithIndex` starts at **index 0**.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar fashion as with `zipWithIndex` but starting from a given initial value, zipping with a `Stream` that starts from `1`, for instance as follows,

```
val edges = for ( (e,id) <- s zip Stream.from(1) ) yield 
              new Edge(e.getSrcBlock, e.getDstBlock, id, getArity(e))
```

By associating a companion object to `Edge` with an apply method that takes values used to construct an `Edge` instance, we get a more readable code,

```
class Edge(b1: Block, b2: Block, var id: Int, arity: Int)

object Edge {
  def apply(id: Int, e: SrcDstData) = {
    new Edge(e.getSrcBlock, e.getDstBlock, id, getArity(e))
  }
}
```

Hence

```
val edges = for ( (e,id) <- s zip Stream.from(1)) yield Edge(id,e)
```